# How do I make bundler recognize installed curb gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, feedzirra, curb

I've successfully installed the `curb` gem on Mac OS X using `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install curb` but when trying to run `bundle install` I still get this error:

```
Installing curb (0.7.16) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I've done some digging and it looks like `feedzirra` is requiring the gem (it's not listed in the Gemfile). I've tried adding the gem to the Gemfile and pointing it to `vendor/gems` but that didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, sorry if there's more clarification needed. This is my first question and I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails. I'll be glad to provide more details if necessary.

Comment: Does `gem list curb` show that version 0.7.16 is installed? If not try installing that exact version.

Comment: I get  *** LOCAL GEMS ***  
curb (0.7.16)

Answer (score 6):

Apparently it needs SSL support for curl, as I had the same error and fixed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

You might want to try a standard "gem install curb" to see if that works before "bundle install".

Answer (score 0):

in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'curb', '= 0.7.16', :path => 'vendor/gems/curb'
```

As long as that's where you installed the gem to.

Comment: The path is `'vendor/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/curb-0.7.16'` and I've tried adding the line you suggested with that path. Still didn't work. I wonder if the -0.7.16 at the end affects it at all?  


I get this error when running bundle install after adding the :path

  
`Could not find gem 'curb (>= 0) ruby' in source at vendor/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/curb-0.7.16.
Source does not contain any versions of 'curb (>= 0) ruby'`

Comment: @ChristopherCortez drop the dash-version-number, but add it to the string if you have one. Answer updated.